# Java- Mapstruct : Mapping of specific field from source to target which is inside a List Object

Tags: java, nested, mapping, mapstruct

Suppose I have the below scenario:

```
class A{
     List<B> objB;
     Person objPerson;
} 

class B{
    String name;
    String countryCode;
}

Now I want to map the source "A" above to target below:

class Target{
   SomeWrapperClass objWrapper;
}

class SomeWrapperClass{
   List<C> objC;
   Person objPerson;
}

class C{
   String code;
}
```

Is there a way to map the value of 'countryCode' to 'code'. Source is **Class A** and Target is **Class Target**

I tried using @Mapping but it didn't help.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Java. I would like to convert the source class to target class as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm .. to solution mapper would be below according to your theoretical piece of code.

```
@Mapper
public interface SomeMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "objWrapper.objC", source = "a.objB")
    @Mapping(taget = "objWrapper.objPerson", source = "a.objPerson")    
    SomeWrapperClass mapToSomeWrapperClass(A a);

    @Mapping(target = "code", source = "countryCode")
    C mapToC(B b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can't this be done in a single mapping using @Mapping? I mean I want to return SomeWrapperClass as a single object with all conversions inside it. Any idea if its even possible.